# Pagina atualizando automaticamente, JSF

Tags: jsf

Tenho um método chamado por um poll, ele é chamado a cada 20 segundos mas demora cerca de 1 minuto para terminar de ser executado. Até aí tudo bem, mas preciso que minha tela jsf seja atualizada a cada 10-15 segundos, sem ter de esperar que meu método de 1 minuto de duração termine.

Resumindo:

Preciso que minha página atualize enquanto um método chamado por um poll está sendo executado.

Isso é possível?

Comment: esse seu método traz informações para algum componente?

Comment: Pode usar o <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20" /> 
Ai a cada 20 segundos ele da um F5 na páginal....

Comment: Sim Rafael, tenho um datatable que tem uma lista de objetos que são atualizados no método

Comment: Gustavo, já tentei usar o metta tag refresh e não deu certo...